# Threading inside For Loop And While Using Events In Tkinter~Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Trying a scenario where in I wanted to proceed in the for loop based on threading mechanism [for syncing/wait mechanism] as shown in the code below.

```
#!/tools/bin/python

# Global Import Variables
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import shlex
import os 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import string
import threading

class test_template:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.next_button = None
        self.fruit_lbl = None
        self.yes_button = None
        self.no_button = None
        self.yes_no_button_done = threading.Event()

        # For Loop Goes From 0 To 10
        for i in range (10):
            if not (self.fruit_lbl):
                self.fruit_lbl = Label(root, text="Do You Want To Change The Color Of Fruit %d"%i)
                self.fruit_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
            if not (self.yes_button): 
                self.yes_button = Button(root, background="lawn green", activebackground="forest green", text="YES", command=self.yes_button_code).grid(row=2, column=1)    
            if not (self.no_button): 
                self.no_button = Button(root, background="orange red", activebackground="orangered3", text="NO", command=self.no_button_code).grid(row=2, column=2)    

            while not self.yes_no_button_done.isSet():
                self.yes_no_button_done.wait()

    def yes_button_code(self):
        print "Inside YES Button Config"
    def no_button_code(self):
        print "Inside No Button Config"
        self.yes_no_button_done.set()

# Top Local Variables
root = Tk()
#root.configure(background='black')

# Top Level Default Codes
my_gui = test_template(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Its like the for loop needs to wait until I press either Yes Or No, until then the while loop should be waiting for the event set.

But somehow the threading/wait mechanism is not working fine i.e. as soon I launch the code, its goes into the while loop and goes haywire. Am I missing anything on the above code ? Share in your comments !!

Comment: Does the thread needs to be started or something like that ? Because in some examples, they show like self.yes_no_button_done.start() !!  Is this required ?? 

Any reason why its going into the loop waiting in the while loop ?

Comment: Huff... Hmm.. Clueless !!! Any comments ? Guess ? Or Is there any better way of inter-process communication or threading ?

Comment: Hi this would only loop once though right? you are asking 'if not' and then setting the variables on the first loop. The second loop would just be the remaining yes or no button? and from what I see you are never setting 'yes_no_button_done' to anything.. you are just saying set(). Im not sure I completely understand why you need to thread anything in this code? could you explain simply what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: @Luke.py The scenario is like:
a. The for loop gets started, and in every iteration it asks "Do you want to change the color of fruit: Yes No.
b. After which the while loop waits on yes_no_button_done event.
c. So the control goes to Yes Or No Button Code, so until then I expect it to wait in the while loop inside for.d. In the "No" button code, I set the yes_no_button_done event.
e. So was expectation is, once I press "No" the For loop proceeds to the next loop iteration and continues.When You say "from what I see you are never setting 'yes_no_button_done' to anything" what does it mean?

Comment: @Luke.py: Any comments Luke ? Hope the above info was useful ? Let me know if you need more info.
Have captured another example with adding time and delay but still the same behavior.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154828/any-best-threading-or-communication-events-between-two-operations-in-python-tk

Answer (score 0):

If I have undertood you correctly I dont think that you need to use threading at all. Consider the following:

```
from Tkinter import *


class test_template:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.loop_count = IntVar()
        self.loop_count.set(1)

        l = Label(self.master, text='Change colour of fruit?')
        l.pack()
        count = Label(self.master, textvariable = '%s' % self.loop_count)
        count.pack()
        yes = Button(self.master, text = 'YES', command = self.loop_counter)
        yes.pack() 
        no = Button(self.master, text = 'NO', command = self.loop_counter)
        no.pack()

    def loop_counter(self):
        if self.loop_count.get() == 10:
            print 'Finished'
            self.master.quit()
        else:
            self.loop_count.set(self.loop_count.get()+1)
            print self.loop_count.get()


root = Tk()
GUI = test_template(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Let me know what you think.

Cheers,
Luke